# Dimensionar tamanho de input dentro de table

Tags: html

#### Cenário teste

Tenho uma `table` dentro de um `form`, pois preciso fazer um `form` alinhando linhas e colunas para os `inputs`.

Exemplo:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size: 0.8rem">

 <thead>
  <th class="table-dark" colspan="11">Discriminação da operação</th>
 </thead>

 <thead>
  <th class="table-secondary">.</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">A A A</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">B B B</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">C C C</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">D D D</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">E E E</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">F F F</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">G G G</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">H H H</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">I I I</th>
  <th class="table-secondary">J J J</th>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th class="table-secondary">Valores A</th>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="table-secondary">Valores B</th>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="table-secondary">Valores C</th>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>

</table>
```

---

#### Problema

Preciso diminuir o tamanho de alguns `inputs`.

Tentei:

```
<td><input type="number" name="" width="10px"></td>

<td width="10px"><input type="number" name=""></td>
```

Mas não tive sucesso.

---

- Como poderia diminuir estes inputs?

Comment: Meu querido seguidor downvoter nunca falha! Meu fã :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode selecionar ins inputs pelo CSS e colocar um `max-width`. Não sei se é isso que queria...

Mas primeiro repare que usar `width=""` direto na tag não é recomendado. O próprio validador da W3C acusa erro caso vc use o atributo `width` direto na tag. Usar dessa forma é como se fazia no `HTML4` e deve ser evitado, apesar de ainda funcionar com algumas tags como `canvas`, `img`, `iframe`, etc, mas o indicado atualmente é usar `style="width:xx;"`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo usando o `width` pelo CSS

```css
input {
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size: 0.8rem">

    <thead>
        <th class="table-dark" colspan="11">Discriminação da operação</th>
    </thead>

    <thead>
        <th class="table-secondary">.</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">A A A</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">B B B</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">C C C</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">D D D</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">E E E</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">F F F</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">G G G</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">H H H</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">I I I</th>
        <th class="table-secondary">J J J</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-secondary">Valores A</th>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-secondary">Valores B</th>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-secondary">Valores C</th>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Se vc quiser mudar o tamanho dos inputs só de uma linha vc pode colocar algo como

```
tr:nth-child(2) input {
    max-width: 50px;
}
tr {
    text-align: center;
}
```

E vc vai ter um resultado como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]